# How to add a bolean series to a new column in df2 IF multiple conditions in df1 are met (incl. DATETIME)?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have two pandas dataframes. `df1` contains server error logs (~50 million rows):

**Error Log**

```
Room    Server  DATETIME        Error_Message
1       A       9/22/2016 12:42 A1
2       A       9/6/2016 5:47   A1
3       B       9/6/2016 1:20   B1
4       B       9/16/2016 18:07 B1
5       C       9/22/2016 6:15  Z9
```

`df2` contains server downtime events (~200 rows):

**Breakdown events**

```
    Room    Server  DATETIME            
    1       A       9/22/2016 13:42
    2       A       9/6/2016 6:47
    3       C       9/6/2016 3:20
    4       B       9/16/2016 19:07
    5       C       9/22/2016 7:15
```

First, I want to add additional columns to `df2` (one for each error code) that indicates presence/absence of that error code in `df1`.

The first condition is that the error code should only be listed as `Yes` in `df2` if it occurs within a specific time window prior to the breakdown event mentioned in `df2` *in this case one hour* (Yes/No).

The second condition is that it should only be `Yes` if `Room` and `Server` key values match (i.e. if it is the same server in the same room), otherise `No`

**Desired Output**

```
Room    Server  DATETIME            Error_A1_1h Error_B1_1h Error_Z9_1h    
1       A       9/22/2016  13:42    Yes         No          No
2       A       9/6/2016    6:47    Yes         No          No
3       C       9/6/2016    3:20    No          No          No
4       B       9/16/2016  19:07    No          Yes         No
5       C       9/22/2016   7:15    No          No          Yes
```

How can I do this in a memory-efficient way (I have 64 GB RAM)? It is simple in SQL, but I did not yet come to a solution in python.

Comment: can you elaborate the error code in df1 more ---- you want to list the error Yes in df2 only if they occurred before the DATETIME value in df2, plus the Room and Server value in df1 and df2 also matches ?

Comment: I want to list the "error Yes" in df2 only IF it occurred in a given, user-specified time window before the breakdown event. This means that the error message should have been logged (1) before the DATETIME in df2 BUT (2) not longer than X minutes before that (in this case 1h).